# STAssertEqualObjects not working with NSString using OCUnit in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, ocunit

Can't figure out whats going on here . . .

I've got a simple unit test thats designed to test a parser. Test case looks like this:

```
[parser didStartElement:@"mobileresponse" attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"http://www.espn.com/" forKey:@"rooturl"]];
[parser didStartElement:@"content" attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"/soccer" forKey:@"mobileFriendlyUrl"]];
NSString *mobileFriendlyURL = [parser valueForKey:@"mobile_friendly_url"];
STAssertEqualObjects(@"http://www.espn.com/soccer", mobileFriendlyURL, @"url path should be appended to root url");
```

now this is failing every time, but here is the output

```
'http://www.espn.com/soccer' should be equal to 'http://www.espn.com/soccer' url path should be appended to root url
```

Am I going crazy or are those the exact same?? Does anyone have any idea why this is throwing an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well most probably the reason for this is that `[parser valueForKey:@"mobile_friendly_url"]` doesn't return an `NSString`.

Consider this example (the error is there to make a point):

```
NSString *mobileFriendlyURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.espn.com/soccer"];
STAssertEqualObjects(@"http://www.espn.com/soccer", mobileFriendlyURL, @"");
```

This will fail with the same message as yours because you have compared 2 objects that are different (even if you **assumed** that `mobileFriendlyURL` was an `NSString` and declared its type as `NSString`). Finally the message just prints the `description` of the `NSURL` which is of course identical to your string and thus confusing you even more :)

A quick way to test this theory is to do something like this:

```
NSString *mobileFriendlyURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.espn.com/soccer"] description];
STAssertEqualObjects(@"http://www.espn.com/soccer", mobileFriendlyURL, @"");
```

Or even better do something similar to this in order to query the class:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [mobileFriendlyURL class]);
```

I hope that this makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

just had to change the nsstring declaration to

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[parser valueForKey:@"mobile_friendly_url"]];
```